# how to split a list of numpy arrays based on two conditions

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, split

I have a list of including numpy array and want to rearrange it using two numbers. This is my list:

```
all_data=[np.array([[1., 1., 0.],[1., 1., 0.2],[1., 1., 0.1]]),\
          np.array([[2., 2., 0.1],[2., 2., 0.1],[2., 2., 0.1]]),\
          np.array([[3., 3., 0.2],[3., 3., 0.2],[3., 3., 0.2]]),\
          np.array([[1., 1., 100.],[1., 1., 110.],[1., 1., 110.]]),\
          np.array([[2., 2., 100.],[2., 2., 100.],[2., 2., 100.]]),\
          np.array([[3., 3., 100.],[3., 3., 110.],[3., 3., 120.]])]
```

These are my numbers:

```
n_iteration=3
n_layer=2
```

`n_iteration` gives me the number of iterations that I have and `n_layer` gives me the number data sets that I have in each iteration. It means I have two data sets in each iteration. At the moment, my `all_data` has `6` arrays. First three arrays are representing the data related to the first data set in three iterations. The last three arays are also the data for next data set in the three iteration. In other words, data sets are sorted out based on their iteration number but I want to sort iterations based on the data sets. I have written some simple data to make also a visual difference from my `all_data` to desired output. I want to have a list of sublists in which number of sublists is equal to `n_iteration` and numbers of arrays in each sublist equals `n_layer`:

```
[[np.array([[1., 1., 0.],[1., 1., 0.2],[1., 1., 0.1]]),\
  np.array([[1., 1., 100.],[1., 1., 110.],[1., 1., 110.]])],\
 [np.array([[2., 2., 0.1],[2., 2., 0.1],[2., 2., 0.1]]),\
  np.array([[2., 2., 100.],[2., 2., 100.],[2., 2., 100.]])],\
 [np.array([[3., 3., 0.2],[3., 3., 0.2],[3., 3., 0.2]]),\
  np.array([[3., 3., 100.],[3., 3., 110.],[3., 3., 120.]])]]
```

I tried the following code but it is giving me something else:

```
arranged_data=[]
for i in range (int (len(all_data)/n_iteration)):
    arranged_data.append([all_data[i], all_data[int (i+n_layer)]])
```

In advance, I do appreciate any help.

Comment: At the risk of me misunderstanding the question: Why not simply make another numpy array from the initial list and reshape it according to `n_iteration` and `n_layer`?

Comment: Dear @Roland Deschain, is it possible to do so? I just want to finally have a list which has some sublists and these sublists are data sets created in each iteration.

Comment: It should be. simply use `my_nparray = np.array(all_data).reshape(n_iteration, n_layer, 3,3)`. It gives you an array, which should have the desired shape. From there it is simply a matter of casting it back (np.arrays have a tolist() method for this). I'm not sure if it is the most efficient way to do this, but it should work, provided, the reshaping parameters match the arrays.

Comment: dear @Roland Deschain, thanks for giving time to my issue. I tried your solution but it is giving me something else. The result is not like my expected results.

Comment: There are duplicates that make it difficult to link the desired output to the input. Maybe you want get rid of the duplicates and post an example where it is clear where each element goes, I mean a univocal relation between input and output elements.

Comment: Dear @iGian, I selected the data to make a visualization about my rearrangement. first three rows of `all_data` are sorted from 1 to 3 to show the three iterations. And from row 4 to 6 again sorted from 1 to 3 to show iterations. I want to put ones, twos and threes as sublists. I thought maybe it is possible to it using `n_iteration` and `n_layer`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I got the point, but maybe this is working as expected. Or not.

I'm using this data input, which is more readable:

```
all_data=[np.array([[1.],[2.],[3.]]),
          np.array([[4.],[4.],[4.]]),
          np.array([[5.],[5.],[5.]]),
          np.array([[6.],[7.],[7.]]),
          np.array([[8.],[8.],[8.]]),
          np.array([[9.],[10.],[11.]])]
```

First convert the list into a numpy array:

```
data_np = np.array(all_data)
```

Then, given the variables build an array with the indexes of the row you want to group:

```
layers = 3
iterations = 2
rows = np.array([np.array([i, i+layers]) for i in range(layers)])
```

Where `rows` results in

```
array([[0, 3],
       [1, 4],
       [2, 5]])
```

Now, use the numpy indexing:

```
res = data_np[rows]
```

Reshaping the `res` array, you should get your output (as a numpy array):

```
res.reshape(1, layers, iterations, layers)[0]
# array([[[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
#         [ 6.,  7.,  7.]],
# 
#        [[ 4.,  4.,  4.],
#         [ 8.,  8.,  8.]],
# 
#        [[ 5.,  5.,  5.],
#         [ 9., 10., 11.]]])
```

Comment: Dear @iGian, Thanks for you solution but the ppoint is that your method is not working for my input data. You have changed the input and when I try this method for my own input, I cannot achieve what I wanted.